# When I launch my Flutter application on macOS, the application is empty

Tags: flutter, macos

When I launch my Flutter application on macOS, it displays nothing but a black screen on the app.

[image]
It also causes the Mac to **panic**, displaying black dots and pieces of applications on top of other applications. The Mac heats up, and console problems and errors are very random.

I've found this issue, but it doesn't help https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/125025.

flutter doctor -v [image]

I tried to start it with and without the debugger but it didn't make any difference.

However, Chrome and Windows 11 displays the application correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
<true/>
```

to `DebugProfile.entitlements` but remove it from `Release.entitlements` when you want to distribute to app store.

files are located in `flutter_folder/macos/Runner`

Comment: It's already on true and the problem isn't just with my app, but with all Flutter apps